# How to set the current timestamp and get the reminder timestamp?

Tags: java, android

I want to set the timestamp and the reminder timestamp, for 3 hours for example, in SharedPreferences and then get the reminder timestamp. Then if 3 hours have passed, show an action. I have searched everywhere but I can't find an solution.

I have tried this code but it is not complete and I can't figure how to set and get the reminder timestamp:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
long currentTimeStamp = c.getTimeInMillis();
long reminderTimeStamp = getReminderTime();
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    Log.v(TAG, "currentTimeStamp=" + currentTimeStamp);
    Log.v(TAG, "reminderTimeStamp=" + reminderTimeStamp);
}

if (currentTimeStamp > reminderTimeStamp) {

    //DO SOME ACTION

}
```

Comment: So you want this to be done in the background?

Comment: Hi I Want To Do This in oncreate or in background i have not decided this yet

Comment: If I were you, I would make a alarm manager and set it for the time needed. If you need code I could make you a quick sample.

Comment: Ok i will try that can you please send me the code :)

Comment: Hey Can You Please Send Me The Sample That You Say i really need it as fast as possible :(

Comment: I think this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example